# Storing Session Data Securely With Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, session, user-data

For all of my projects I use codeigniter as my framework. I always use sessions in order to get store things like user_string and user_permissions to determine who can access certain functions and pages within the site.

Is it bad practise to use the `session->userdata` as a basis to provide a user unique content?

I usually set a user an array of userdata when they login, like so:

```
$data = array('id' => $user_string, 
              'g' => $user_group);

$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

When I'm determining what results they get for a query I might do the following:

```
function get_posts(){
    if( $this->session->userdata('g') == 2 ){
        $data = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('' => $this->session->userdata('id') ) )->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Is this code vulnerable because of the `session->userdata('id')` and `session->userdata('g')`?

Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use this, without any worry!! For extra security set **sess_encrypt_cookie** to true in your config file

Comment: Not sure if you're talking about [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation), Code Igniter's implementation or the whole concept of sessions :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario It's just to determine what I'm doing is correct and good practice? Just so I'm not introducing bad habits into my code.

Answer (score 0):

just do one think:-
 save your key to your application/config/config.php, open the file and set

```
$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";

$this->load->library('encrypt');

data = array('id' => $this->encrypt->encode($user_string), 
              'g' => $this->encrypt->encode($user_group),
```

);

```
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

when get data:-

```
function get_posts(){
    if( $this->session->userdata('g') == 2 ){
          $id =$this->encrypt->decode($this->session->userdata('id') );
        $data = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('' =>  $id ) )->result_array();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this protects against a malicious hacker who compromises your server and gains write access to session dir but somehow remains unable to read anything else. It's an unlikely scenario, isn't it? It's like undressing in the dark just in case a stranger broke in your house.